# Keras uses only one core

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow backend. The problem is that only one core of my cpu is being actively used during training. I declare my model in following way:

```
class GAN():
    def __init__(self):
        with k.backend.name_scope("Discriminator"):
            self.discriminator = build_discriminator(input_shape, 
                                                     discriminanator_units)
            self.discriminator.compile(optimizer=k.optimizers.Adam(0.0005),
                                       loss=k.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                                       metrics=[k.metrics.binary_accuracy])


        with k.backend.name_scope("Generator"):
            discriminator_frozen = k.Model(self.discriminator.inputs,
                           self.discriminator.outputs,
                           name="Disc_frozen")
            discriminator_frozen.trainable = False

            ... # declare input placeholders

            self.generator = build_generator(input_shape, generator_units)
            self.prediction = self.generator(inputs=input_list)

            ...  # some Lambda layers

            evaluation = discriminator_frozen(self.positions_pelvis_relative)
            self.combined = k.Model(inputs=[*input_list,
                                            self.mask,
                                            self.adjacency],
                                    outputs=[evaluation])
            self.combined.compile(optimizer=k.optimizers.Adam(0.0015),
                                  loss=self.gan_loss,
                                  metrics=[self.displacement_loss,
                                           self.discriminator_loss,
                                           self.adjacency_loss])
```

When i pretrain `self.discriminator`, all of the CPU cores are being used, but when i train it interchangeably with generator, only 1 core is used.

Comment: If it's pure Python, it can only use a single CPU, by design. Google "GIL".

Comment: @tripleee, It is said that both tensorflow and keras implicitly handle multi-processing, so i have no opportunity to intervene in this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that there was a random sampling operation in generator training phase that bottlenecked the whole process. I've created a dataset of random noise and sampled from it, after this all of the CPU cores were used.

Comment: Did You remember how did you turn off random sampling?

Comment: @PeterPirog I used cpu-based very narrow sampling operation, current sampling implementations are very fast if done in vectorized manner